# Is it wrong to say "at Facebook" since Facebook is no longer a company?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is it wrong to say **at Facebook** since Facebook is no longer a company but a product? I mean, we say **at a company** but we don't say **at a product**. Is this correct?

> **At Meta**, there are times when engineers have to work nights, weekends and holidays to develop **Facebook Reels**, a short-form
> video feature, to compete with TikTok and Youtube Shorts.

> **At Facebook**, there are times when engineers have to work nights, weekends and holidays to develop **Reels**, a short-form video
> feature, to compete with TikTok and Youtube Shorts.

Comment: Do people still informally refer to the company as "Facebook"? If they do, then "at Facebook" is fine. This isn't a question about English Language, but about the ways people refer to a particular company that has changed its name.

Comment: What are the two block quotes? You seem to be asking about the second one, which says "at Facebook". Is that from a book, a news article, etc.? And where does the first block quote come from?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, I wrote the two quotes. I want to use "at Facebook" because many people don't know Meta. But I'm worried "at Facebook" is wrong because Facebook is now a product and not a company.

Comment: This isn't a question about ELL. It asks for an opinion about a company name. IMHO it will be known as "Facebook" (or Faceplant as I call it) for a long time to come as the public are used to "Facebook" and "Facebook" it will stay. Nobody outside Meta cares that they have changed the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a technical or legal sense.

No, because in everyday use, Facebook is still used colloquially as if it was the name of the company.

It would be acceptable to say:

> I've been working at Facebook (or perhaps I should say "Meta" now) for 5 years.

But if you were filling out a job application you would say that you are working "at Meta", because that is a formal or legal context.